# Set resource image to button Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, .net, user-interface

What's the correct way to set an Image to a button on Windows Forms (Visual Studio C++)?

I added the image by right clicking on my project name (on Solution Explorer), then "Add existing item..." and then selecting the image. But when I try to set the image using

```
myProject.Properties.Resources.Image01;
```

on the right side, it doesn't work because detects `myProject` as a namespace.

What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

TO access the recourses will be better choice

> pictureBox1.Image = ProjectName.Properties.Resources.ImageName;

Note the following:

- The resource image file is "ImageName.png", file extension should be
  omitted.

Comment: But ProjectName doesn't works, it's neccesary to do something extra?